# Remove "back and forth" sliding effect from Owl Carousel v1

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Owl Carousel v2 has `"autoplay"` property that slides "left to right",

But on v1  `"autoPlay"` property slides "left to right & back and forth".

I want to remove "back" sliding effect especially after all sliding item reaches to last. I just want as v2, i.e keep on sliding from "left to right" only.

how can we do this on owl-carousel v1 ? Suggestions please.

Comment: `rewindNav:false` is what you want?

Comment: Ya, "rewindNav:false" solved my problem. But what i also wanted is keep on sliding from left to right. what i did is "loop:true". But sliding stops after slide item reaches to last.

Comment: That is supported only with single item per slide.

Comment: For mobile device i have only one item per slide, But, this doesn't happen as you said.

Comment: Provide a `transitionStyle`